# C++ Binary search turns into infinite loop

Tags: c++, binary-search

Not sure where went wrong, this program works for some numbers in the array, but not all of them. And when I search a number that doesn't exist in the array, sometimes it returns -1, sometimes it turns into an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary_search(int var, int arr[], int quant){
    
    int low, high, mid;
    int ind=0;
    bool found;
    
    low=0;
    high =quant-1;
    found = false;
    
    while ((found == false) && (low<=high)){
    
        mid = (high+low)/2+1;
 
        if (arr[mid] == var){
            ind=mid;
            found = true;
            cout<<ind<<endl;

        }
        else if (arr[mid]>var){
            high = mid-1;

            }
        else
            low = mid+1;
    
    }
    if (found == true)
        return ind;
    else
        return -1;
    

}

int main() {
    int a =4;
    int lst[7] = {0, 1, 2, 18, 19, 20, 25};
    int b = 7;
    cout<<binary_search(a,lst,b)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: When will `low<=high` ever be false?

Comment: and use `std::midpoint` and iterators or `std::size_t` for indexes.

Comment: Can you provide specific examples of this misbehavior?

Comment: And return `std::optional<std::size_t>` or an iterator.

Comment: `mid = (high+low)/2+1;` seems suspicious.  If `high` is `1` and `low` is `1`, should `mid` really be `2`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `mid = (high+low)/2+1;`. Imagine `low=5` and `high=5` so `mid=6` which would lead to inifinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary_search(int var, int arr[], int quant){
    int low = 0, high = quant - 1, mid;

    while (low<=high){

        mid = (high+low)/2;

        if (arr[mid] == var) return mid;
        else if (arr[mid]>var) high = mid-1;
        else low = mid+1;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int a =4;
    int lst[7] = {0, 1, 2, 18, 19, 20, 25};
    int b = 7;
    cout<<binary_search(18,lst,b)<<endl;
    cout<<binary_search(25,lst,b)<<endl;
    cout<<binary_search(a,lst,b)<<endl;
}
```

I removed the variable `found` because you can return the index immediately after finding the target variable from the array. And I added 2 more `couts` to test if it works.